# Can't get xdotool to Ctrl+Tab after loading chromium-browser Pi-3 Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, chromium

After following Dan Purdy's instructions for getting chromium-browser into kiosk mode with 3 tabs open I tried numerous variations using xdotool to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> through the website ever 30 seconds.  I think this came closest but still hangs on the first tab:

```
@lxterminal watch -n30 "xdotool search --onlyvisible class "chromium" windowfocus && xdotool ctrl+Tab
```

I have a feeling I'm close but just missing something with syntax.

Answer (score -2):

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "chromium" windowfocus && xdotool key ctrl+Tab
```

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include some explanation here, e.g. what do these commands do?